# Django or Nodejs or Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, python, ruby-on-rails, django, node.js

I want to learn web development, I know little bit Python and Nodejs.
I dont have any knowledge on Ruby.

So, In the below 3, which one should I choose for Web Development?

1. Django
2. Nodejs
3. Ruby on Rails

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say Nodejs, its the simplest of the 3.

Comment: Thanks Brainiac, but Nodejs works async in nature, so isn't that hard when going deeper in that?

Comment: You can't compare node.js with web-frameworks, since it's not one

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the place for this question...it's way too broad, and any answer will be fairly opinion-based.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac let me take a look at your node.js tag score :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course this question will be opinionated because it's fairly broad. Everyone has their own preferred choice. Though if you are a beginner to web programming and you'd like to use python I'd say start with [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).